# Text - extract sentences from text file that have certain characters python

Tags: python, text, character, extract, sentence

I am having a text file(consider it as main.txt) which has multiple language contents and I am having a charcter set text file which has particular characters. For example: character set text file contains

```
a
b
c
d
```

I want to extract lines from main.txt. If any characters other than a,b,c,d is present. It should not be extracted.

My code:

```
character_set = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    if any([character in character_set for character in line]):
        with open('text.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf8') as f:
            f.write(line)
```

It gives output in such a way that if any one of the character from a,b,c,d is present, then that line is extracted.

**Expected Output:**

Don't Extract lines that have character other than a,b,c,d.

So the logic is different for this.
Help me in this problem

Answer (score 0):

```py
character_set = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
with open('text.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for character in line.readlines():
        if character.strip() not in character_set:
            f.write(character.strip())
```

I haven't tested this yet. Hopefully I helped something!

Comment: No, This extracts lines having d,e,f,g,h... But what I need is extract lines other than d,e,f,g,h...

Comment: So try to remove the `not` from this line: `if character.strip() not in character_set:`

Answer (score 0):

use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)s:

```
character_set = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
# or even:
# character_set = set('abcd')

# ... open the file you read from and the one you write to.
for line in in_file:
        if not set(line) - character_set:
            out_file.write(line)
```